# webapps missing from Tomcat on VPS

Tags: tomcat, vps

I am trying to put a war file on my VPS. However it is missing the webapps folder.

[image: VPS snapshot]

Tomcat 7 is there but I am scratching my head on where the webapps folder is.

This is my first attempt on deploying a war file on a server, I have only done it on my local.

When I find the webapps, how do I link it to a domain?

Lets say I have a site called www.foo.com and a war file called software.war. How can I link the war file to the domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the concept of CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE for tomcat installations. You're obviously on some unix machine and I imagine that tomcat has been installed from that distribution.

Assuming you're running Ubuntu, check [this documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135824/what-is-the-tomcat-installation-directory) on where to find the directories you're looking for. They're typically spread to blend into the unix way to look at directories, e.g. configuration in /etc. Odds are that you'll find it in `/var/lib/tomcat7`, but it might also be elsewhere, depending on your distribution.

Alternatively, run `find / -name webapps` to search for a directory anywhere in the filesystem (under the root folder).